# whether or not CX5 need dpdk-devbind.py to bind nic businfo

Tags: mellon

dpdk 18.11 , when use mlx5 nic, use dpdk-devbind.py -b igb_uio 0000:xx:00.0 ,it show mlx5_pci_probe(): no Verbs device matches PCI device 0000:xx:00.0, are kernel drivers loaded?

whether or not use dpdk-devbind.py -b igb_uio 0000:xx:00.0

Comment: the answer to your problem is shared. Please evaluate and close the ticket by accepting and upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

MLX5 PMD does not require `dpdk-devbind.py -b igb_uio` it works independent to `igb_uio,uio_pci_generic` on both Linux and Windows.

Please re-test without binding

```
 lspci -ks 0000:41:00.1
41:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT2892 Family [ConnectX-6 Dx]
        Subsystem: Mellanox Technologies MT2892 Family [ConnectX-6 Dx]
        Kernel driver in use: mlx5_core
```

From DPDK documentation [refer](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/mlx5.html) & also refer [for DPDK 16.04](https://dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/v16.04/nics/mlx5.html)

```
This capability allows the PMD to coexist with kernel network interfaces which remain functional, although they stop receiving unicast packets as long as they share the same MAC address. This means legacy linux control tools (for example: ethtool, ifconfig and more) can operate on the same network interfaces that owned by the DPDK application.
```

Comment: @liangbo please accept or upvote to close the question. as it will help others understand it is the solution